# Trouble understanding notation of symplectic forms, differential forms and differentials

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

I found the exerpt below in the book "Introduction to Symplectic Topology".
I understand that a 2-form $\omega(p,\zeta, \zeta')$ on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is a function that maps $\mathbb R^{2n}\times\mathbb R^{2n}\times\mathbb R^{2n}$ to $\mathbb R$. If $\omega$ is independent of $p$, then it essentially maps $\mathbb R^{2n}\times\mathbb R^{2n}$ to $\mathbb R$. That's why I can understand

$$\omega_0(\zeta,\zeta')=\sum_{j=1}^n (\xi_j \eta_j' - \eta_j\xi_j')$$

But what is

$$\omega_0 =\sum_{j=1}^n dx_j\land dy_j$$
and why is it equivalent to the above? What exactly do they mean with $dx_j$ and $dx_j\land dy_j$ here?

I should note that the first $n$ components of $\zeta$ are denoted $\xi$ or $x$ and the last $n$ components of $\zeta$ are denoted $\eta$ or $y$.

> **The symplectic form**
>
> Consider the $2$-form
> $$\omega_0:=\sum_{j=1}^n dx_j\wedge dy_j\tag{1.1.20}$$
> on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. We can think of this either as a differential form on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with constant coefficients, or as a nondegenerate skew-symmetric bilinear form
> $$\omega_0:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\times\mathbb{R}^{2n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
> on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. (The two notions coincide when the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is viewed as the tangent space of the manifold $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ at a point $z$.) The value of $\omega_0$ on a pair of vectors $\zeta=(\xi,\eta)$ and $\zeta'=(\xi',\eta')$ with $\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta'\in\mathbb{R}$ is given by
> $$\omega_0(\zeta,\zeta')=\sum_{j=1}^n(\xi_j\eta_j'-\eta_j\xi_j')=\langle J_0\zeta,\zeta'\rangle=-\zeta^TJ_0\zeta'.\tag{1.1.21}$$

Comment: Respectfully, I strongly suggest learning the basics of differential forms (a.k.a. "calculus on manifolds") before attempting to learn an advanced subject like symplectic topology.  To answer your question: the object $dx_j$ is a $1$-form, while $dx_j \wedge dy_j$ is a $2$-form, and $\wedge$ is the wedge product.  But again, this sort of thing is typically prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: I second what @JesseMadnick said.

Comment: " is typically prerequisite knowledge"
I did not know what a manifold is a week ago. I'm just a physicist, not a mathematician. 
Anyway, with your help and wikipedia's, I found the solution (I posted it below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we define

$$ dx_j(\zeta) = \xi_j $$
$$ dy_j(\zeta) = \eta_j $$

and we define the exterior product [like wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form#Exterior_product):

$$ (f\wedge g)(v_1,\ldots, v_{k+\ell})=\frac{1}{k!\ell!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+\ell}} (sgn(\sigma)) f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})g(v_{\sigma(k+1)}
,\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+\ell)}) $$

then

$$\omega_0(\zeta, \zeta') =\sum_{j=1}^n (dx_j\land dy_j)(\zeta, \zeta')
= \sum_{j=1}^n (dx_j(\zeta) dy_j(\zeta') - dx_j(\zeta') dy_j(\zeta)) = \sum_{j=1}^n (\xi_j \eta_j' - \eta_j\xi_j') $$